# Manejo de Excepciones en Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excepciones

Como puedo hacer en Rails 4 para pasarle a mi vista la excepción capturada en:

```
rescue Exception => exc  
  # dispone el mensaje de error 
  puts "Error ".concat(exc.message)
```

En la terminal me muestra bien, pero cuando deseo pasarle al view no consigo mostrar son excepciones de la base de datos específicamente *Postgresql* de un trigger que tiene una validación.

Asi tengo mi código:

Este mi controlador

```
def accion
  # Código que puede generar una excepción
rescue Exception => exc  
  # dispone el mensaje de error 
  puts "Aqui si muestra en la terminal ".concat(exc.message)
  @msg = "ERROR: Aqui nada.".concat(exc.message)

  respond_to do |f|
    f.js
  end
end
```

En mi view tengo de está manera

```
<% if @registro %>
   $("<div class='col-sm-12' id='msg-agregar-persona' style='color:#000;padding-top:5px;font-size:10px;background:#d6ffd6;border-radius:5px;text-align:center;'>Registrado Exitosamente.</div>").insertBefore("#form-agregar-persona");
<% else %>
  $("<div class='col-sm-12' id='msg-agregar-persona' style='color:#000;padding-top:5px;font-size:10px;background: #f8dfdf;border-radius:5px;text-align:center;'><%= @msg %></div>").insertBefore("#form-agregar-persona");
<% end %>
```

Y en la consola me muestra:

```
Persona Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "personas".* FROM "personas"  WHERE (documento_persona = '-123' and tipo_documento_id = 1 and nacionalidad_id = 1)
  (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "personas" ("acta", "apellido_persona", "created_at", "documento_persona", "fecha_nacimiento", "folio", "genero_id", "libro", "nacionalidad_id", "nombre_persona", "tipo_documento_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"  [["acta", ""], ["apellido_persona", "portíllo soto"], ["created_at", "2017-06-16 15:35:49.825920"], ["documento_persona", "-123"], ["fecha_nacimiento", "2017-06-30"], ["folio", ""], ["genero_id", 2], ["libro", ""], ["nacionalidad_id", 1], ["nombre_persona", "antonio ramón"], ["tipo_documento_id", 1], ["updated_at", "2017-06-16 15:35:49.825920"]]
  PG::Error: ERROR:  La fecha de nacimiento no puede ser igual o mayor a la fecha actual. Verifique la fecha ingresada
  : INSERT INTO "personas" ("acta", "apellido_persona", "created_at", "documento_persona", "fecha_nacimiento", "folio", "genero_id", "libro", "nacionalidad_id", "nombre_persona", "tipo_documento_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"
  (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Aquí se muestra el error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  La fecha de nacimiento no puede ser igual o mayor a la fecha actual. Verifique la fecha ingresada
: INSERT INTO "personas" ("acta", "apellido_persona", "created_at", "documento_persona", "fecha_nacimiento", "folio", "genero_id", "libro", "nacionalidad_id", "nombre_persona", "tipo_documento_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"
""
Rendered personas/guardar.js.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 25ms (Views: 1.4ms | ActiveRecord: 17.8ms)
```

---

> ```
> def accion
>   # Código que puede generar una excepción
> rescue => e
>   @error = e.message
> end
> ```
>
> accion.html.erb
>
> ```
> <p>Se generó el siguiente error: <%= @error %></p>
> ```

Ya intente realizar este paso también antes pero no me muestra y tampoco me genera ningún error es más:

---

Los registros que se muestran en la consola:

```
 PG::Error: ERROR:  La fecha de nacimiento no puede ser igual o mayor a la fecha actual. Verifique la fecha ingresada
: INSERT INTO "personas" ("acta", "apellido_persona", "created_at", "documento_persona", "fecha_nacimiento", "folio", "genero_id", "libro", "nacionalidad_id", "nombre_persona", "tipo_documento_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"
  Rendered personas/guardar.js.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 33ms (Views: 1.2ms | ActiveRecord: 26.9ms)
```

Comment: El `puts @msg.inspect` ponlo **después** de asignar el valor, es decir, abajo de la línea `@msg = "ERROR: No se ha podido registrar la persona."concat(exc.message)`. ¿Qué se muestra en consola?

Comment: Aqui si muestra el error PG::Error: ERROR:  La fecha de nacimiento no puede ser igual o mayor a la fecha actual. Verifique la fecha ingresada
: INSERT INTO "personas" ("acta", "apellido_persona", "created_at", "documento_persona", "fecha_nacimiento", "folio", "genero_id", "libro", "nacionalidad_id", "nombre_persona", "tipo_documento_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"
"ERROR: No se ha podido registrar la persona."
  Rendered personas/guardar.js.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 56ms (Views: 1.4ms | ActiveRecord: 48.9ms)

Comment: Muestra eso al agregarle puts @msg.inspect no concatena la excepcion a la variable

Comment: Veo que no imprime en consola en absoluto la variable, es decir, esperaría ver por lo menos `ERROR: Aqui nada.` en algún lado de tu log, pero no se ve. ¿Puedes confirmar que `puts @msg` esté, en efecto, después de la asignación de la variable?

Comment: Si imprimo por terminal con el puts el exc.message imprime sin problemas pero en el lado del cliente no lo hace no se si es porque es una variable del sistema o algo así, si a la variable @msg le agrego cualquier valor estático si imprime en la terminal y en la pagina como es debido pero la excepcion en si no he conseguido mostrar del lado del cliente

Comment: Es un comportamiento extraño, no he logrado reproducirlo. ¿Has intentado aislar el comportamiento? Es decir, generar una acción y vista únicamente con el motivo de ver la excepción y ver si el error persiste.

Comment: Buenas Gerry si tambien lo he intentado pero he henido el mismo resultado no se si tiene algo que ver pero uso la versión 4.1.0 de rails no se si tenes algún ejemplo donde consigas mostrar la excepcion de la base de datos en una pagina te lo agradeceria bastante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes guardar el mensaje de tu excepción en una variable y utilizarla en tu vista como lo harías con cualquier otra variable, por ejemplo:

**controlador.rb**

```
def accion
  # Código que puede generar una excepción
rescue Exception => exc  
  # dispone el mensaje de error 
  @msg = "ERROR: ".concat(exc.message)

  respond_to do |f|
    f.js
  end
end
```

**accion.js.erb**

```
$("<div><%= j(@msg) %></div>").insertBefore("#form-agregar-persona");
```

Es **indispensable utilizar `j()` (o `escape_javascript()`)** para indicar que el valor de `@msg` no es *javascript* y por lo tanto lo trate como un texto (o *string*) de lo contrario generará un error ya que intentará ejecutarlo como un código *javascript*.

---

Dicho lo anterior, te recomendaría hacer un mejor manejo de errores, en específico agregando [**validaciones**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) en tu modelo para evitar todas los excepciones que se generen a nivel base de datos.

Por ejemplo: considera un modelo `Usuario` con campos `nombre` y `edad`, donde `edad` es un campo numérico en la base de datos; si envías un dato tipo texto, se generará un error como el que tienes ahora, pero agreguemos validaciones para evitarlo.

**usuario.rb**

```
class Usuario < ApplicationRecord
  validates :edad, numericality: { only_integer: true }
end
```

Esa validación revisará que en efecto el atributo `edad` sea numérico **antes** de guardarlo en la base de datos y, si falla, agregará un error similar a `Edad must be a number` (el cual puedes traducir en tus *locales*) en el objeto que lo esté llamando; por ejemplo:

```
@usuario = Usuario.new(nombre: "Antonio", edad: "diez")
@usuario.save
#=> false

@usuario.errors.full_messages
#=> ["Edad must be a number"]
```

Entonces, en lugar de utilizar una excepción y capturar el mensaje de error en una variable, simplemente utilizas validaciones y muestras los errores del objeto, en caso que existan, por ejemplo:

**accion.html.erb**

```
<p>Se generó el siguiente error: <%= @usuario.errors.full_messages %></p>
```

Esto es sólo un ejemplo de todo lo que puedes lograr con validaciones, te recomiendo leer la [guía de Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) para ver todas las opciones que tienes para validar la información. Este es el flujo correcto que se debe seguir; cachar excepciones es mucho más costoso para tu aplicación así que, en medida de lo posible, es mejor evitarlas.

Comment: @Antonio Ya identifiqué el problema: necesitas indicar que el texto insertado en la vista (i.e el mensaje de error) **no es _javascript_**, es decir, _escapar al javascript_. Ya actualicé la respuesta para reflejar este ajuste y, además, generé un ejemplo en [este repositorio](https://github.com/ggaona/antonio), el cual puedes ver en acción [en este link](https://error-antonio.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: Gerry sos un capo te agradezco bastante me sirvio al primer intento dime hay una manera de ailar el mensaje es decir que solo me muestre el raise exception que yo indique en la funcion un abrazo y gracias nuevamente

Comment: Ya logre encapsular el error he hecho un split del resultado

Comment: @Antonio ¿A qué te refieres con aislar el mensaje?

Comment: mil disculpas por responderte recién creo que me exprese mal como la excepción del motor es algo extensa ejemplo: PG::Error: ERROR:  Ya existe una persona registrada con el Documento Nro. 123
: INSERT INTO "personas" ("acta", "apellido_persona", "created_at", "documento_persona", "fecha_nacimiento", "folio", "genero_id", "libro", "nacionalidad_id", "nombre_persona", "tipo_documento_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id" solo me es preciso mostrar la parte donde indica cual es el inconveniente por eso dije aislar o seria mejor abreviar

Comment: Solo le hice un split y mostre solamente lo primordial del mensaje

Comment: @Antonio Ah, ya entiendo. Gracias por la aclaración. Duda aparate: ¿alguna razón particular por la que usas ese diseño en lugar de utilizar validaciones en tu modelo?

Comment: Programo más en el motor de base de datos uso funciones almacenadas (store procedure, triggers) todo dinámicamente y como estoy empezando con rails aún desconozco todo lo que puedo hacer con la herramienta uso la lógica dentro del base de datos no en la aplicación pero de a poco estaré probando tambien los consejos que me diste

Comment: @Antonio  Listo, me queda claro. Te recomiendo ampliamente leer sobre validaciones, son muy sencillas y, lo más importante, utilizan menos recursos. Suerte!

Comment: gracias @Gerry por tu tiempo y por sobre todo por iluminarme con este problema saludos desde Paraguay