# ¿Cómo validar un select en rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Hola quiero  validar que no valla vació, que tenga escoger una de las opciones.
gracias.

**vista**

```
<% if @reunion.errors %>
 <div class="error">
    <p>Se han encontrado los siguiente errores:</p>
    <ul>
       <% @reunion.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
       <li><%= error %></li>
      <% end %>
   </ul>
</div>
```

```
<div class = "row">
  <div class = "col-md-2"></div>
  <div class ="col-xs-12  col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <label>Negocio</label>
    <%= select_tag "negocio", options_from_collection_for_select(@negocios, "id", "nombre"),
  class: "form-control", :include_blank => "Seleccione Pais"  %>
  </div>  
  <div class ="col-xs-12  col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <label>region</label>
    <%= select_tag "region", "<option value="">Seleccione region</option>".html_safe, 
    class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class ="col-xs-12  col-sm-4 col-md-2">
    <label>ciudad</label>
    <%= select_tag "ciudad", "<option value="">Seleccione una ciudad</option>".html_safe, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class = "col-md-2"></div>
</div>

<div class = "row">
  <div class = "col-md-2"></div>
  <div class ="col-xs-12  col-sm-4 col-md-2">
    <label>Planta</label>
    <%= select_tag "reunion[planta_id]","<option value="">Seleccione una planta</option>".html_safe, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**controlador**

```
class ReunionesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_reunion, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  autocomplete  :centro_costo, :fullname, :full => true, :column_name => 'fullname'

  # GET /reuniones
  # GET /reuniones.json
  def index
    @reuniones = Reunion.all
    @negocios = Negocio.all
  end

  def select_region
    rs = Region.where(:negocio_id => params[:idnegocio]).order('nombre').all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: rs }
      format.html
    end
  end

  def select_ciudad
    rs = Ciudad.where(:region_id => params[:idregion]).order('nombre').all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: rs }
      format.html
    end
  end

  def select_planta
    rs = Planta.where(:ciudad_id => params[:idciudad]).order('nombre').all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: rs }
      format.html
    end
  end

  # GET /reuniones/1
  # GET /reuniones/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /reuniones/new
  def new
    Time.zone = 'America/Bogota' 
    @reunion = Reunion.new(fecha_entrega: Time.zone.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
    @reunion.detalles_reuniones.build
    @negocios = Negocio.all #para javascript
  end

  # GET /reuniones/1/edit
  def edit
    @negocios = Negocio.all
  end

  # POST /reuniones
  # POST /reuniones.json
  def create  
    centro_costo = CentroCosto.find_by(fullname: reunion_params[:centro_costo_fullname])
    @reunion = Reunion.new(reunion_params)
    @reunion.centro_costo_id = centro_costo.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @reunion.save
        format.html { redirect_to @reunion, notice: 'La reunión se creó correctamente.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @reunion }
      else
        @negocios = Negocio.all
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @reunion.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /reuniones/1
  # PATCH/PUT /reuniones/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @reunion.update(reunion_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @reunion, notice: 'La reunión se actualizó correctamente.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @reunion }
      else
        @negocios = Negocio.all
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @reunion.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /reuniones/1
  # DELETE /reuniones/1.json
  def destroy
    @reunion.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to reuniones_url, notice: 'Reunión fue destruida con éxito.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_reunion
    @reunion = Reunion.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def reunion_params
    params.require(:reunion).permit(:hora_pedido, :fecha_pedido,
    :hora_inicio, :hora_final, :fecha_entrega, :observacion, :subtotal,
    :planta_id, :ubicacion,:centro_costo_fullname,:hora_entre,:nombre,
    #Aca esta el maestro de detalle.
    detalles_reuniones_attributes: [:id,:reunion_id, :cantidad, :valor, :producto_id,:_destroy])
  end
end
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
  // Empieza codigo para select anidados
  $("#negocio").change(function(event, data) {
    var id_negocio = $('select#negocio :selected').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: '/reuniones/select_region',
      dataType: "JSON",
      type: 'GET',
      data: { idnegocio: id_negocio },
      success: function(data) {
        var $select = $('#region');
        $select.empty().append('<option value="">Seleccione Region</option>');
        $(data).each(function (index, o) {    
          var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.id).text(o.nombre);
          $select.append($option);
        });      
      }
    });

    // inicializar los selects
    var $select = $('#reunion_planta_id');
    $select.empty().append('<option value="">Seleccione ciudad</option>');
  });

  $("#region").change(function(event, data) {
    var id_region =  $('select#region :selected').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: '/reuniones/select_ciudad',
      dataType: "JSON",
      type: 'GET',
      data: { idregion: id_region },
      success: function(data) {
        var $select = $('#ciudad');
        $select.empty().append('<option value="">Seleccione una ciudad</option>');
        $(data).each(function (index, o) {    
          var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.id).text(o.nombre);
          $select.append($option);
        });      
      }
    });
  });

  $("#ciudad").change(function(event, data) {
    var id_ciudad =  $('select#ciudad :selected').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: '/reuniones/select_planta',
      dataType: "JSON",
      type: 'GET',
      data: { idciudad: id_ciudad },
      success: function(data) {
        var $select = $('#reunion_planta_id');
        $select.empty().append('<option value="">Seleccione la planta</option>');
        $(data).each(function (index, o) {    
          var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.id).text(o.nombre);
          $select.append($option);
        });      
      }
    });
  }); // Termina codigo para select anidado
}); //select reuniones fin de select
```

**Reunion.rb**

```
class Reunion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :planta
end
```

**Lo que muestra en la vista**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**log actualizado.**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Incluye tu modelo (o modelos) donde se guardarán los valores de cada `select`.

Comment: Lo que estás buscando es una validación de datos en el modelo y como presentarla en en tu vista, ¿correcto? De ser así por favor especifícalo en tu pregunta, para que esté claro para todos.

Comment: En la segunda parte de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/79021/42433) puse un ejemplo sobre como funcionan las validaciones, creo que te puede ayudar a entender un poco mejor su uso.

Comment: ¿Qué fallo recibes? ¿Cómo no funciona lo que tienes? Por favor, añade una mejor descripción del problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ¿Cómo validar un select en rails?

Utiliza la validación [`presence`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#presence) para validar que un atributo contenga datos (i.e. no venga en blanco), por ejemplo:

```
class Reunion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :planta

  validates :hora_pedido, presence: true
  validates :fecha_pedido, presence: true
end
```

Esto ocasionará que al momento de guardar un objeto tipo `Reunion` se genere un error en dicho objeto y, por ende no se guarde el registro. Ese error lo puedes obtener llamando `errors` sobre el objeto.

Por ejemplo, en tu caso, no cambiaría nada en tu controlador, tu acción `create` se vería igual, pero al ejecutar esta línea:

```
if @reunion.save
```

Si alguno de los atributos que tienen la validación `presence: true` viene en blanco (i.e. el usuario no los especificó), por ejemplo `hora_pedido`, se agregará un error con un texto similar a `"Hora Pedido can't be blank"`<sup>1</sup> en `@reunion.errors`.

Entonces, lo único que tienes que hacer es incluir una sección en tu vista donde se muestre dicho error (en caso que exista), por ejemplo, podrías agregar este código al inicio de tu vista<sup>2</sup>:

```
<% if @reunion.errors %>
  <div class="error">
    <p>Se han encontrado los siguiente errores:</p>
    <ul>
      <% @reunion.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
        <li><%= error %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Ese código mostrará los errores que se encuentren, en caso que no haya errores no se mostrará nada.

Lo único que debes hacer es agregar tantas validaciones como necesites en tu modelo, el código para mostrar los errores ya no cambia.

Para conocer las validaciones disponibles te recomiendo consultar las [guías de Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html) (contenido en inglés).

<sup>1</sup> *Los mensajes se pueden traducir en `config/locales/`.*

<sup>2</sup> *Pon el código y dale el estilo apropiado de acuerdo al diseño de tu aplicación.*

> NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass)

Este error se muestra debido a que el parámetro `centro_costo_fullname` está vacío (i.e no se proporcionó valor en la forma), lo que ocasiona que el valor de `centro_costo` en la acción `create` de tu controlador sea `nil`:

```
centro_costo = CentroCosto.find_by(fullname: reunion_params[:centro_costo_fullname])
```

Por lo tanto, al intentar asignar el valor `centro_costo.id` a `@reunion.centro_costo_id` se genera el error `NoMethodError` (`centro_costo` al ser `nil` no puede responder a `id`).

Para corregirlo simplemente hay que verificar si `centro_costo` puede responder al método `id` antes de realizar la asignación correspondiente, acción que podemos lograr con `try()`.

Actualiza la acción `create` del controlador para que la línea donde se hace la asignación sea:

```
@reunion.centro_costo_id = centro_costo.try(:id)
```

Entonces, si `centro_costo` es un objeto `CentroCosto` válido, podrá responder a `id` y, por ende, asignará el `id` correspondiente; pero si no lo es, entonces asignará `nil`.

---

Te recomiendo que también consideraras agregar una capa de validación con *javascript*/*jQuery* para ofrecer una mejor experiencia de usuario (además de evitar enviar datos al servidor con cada error del usuario).

Comment: pero seria un ejemplo  de  una validacion con un select

Comment: @juangomez La validación no cambia, el `select` solo indica la forma en que el usuario asignará el valor, pero al modelo siempre le llega igual (e.g. `:planta_id=>"1"`).

Comment: me explico es  que yo estuve buscando validaciones y  no he  encontrado una que me sirva

Comment: @juangomez La validación mostrada en la respuesta debería funcionar para enviar un error si el valo está en blanco. ¿Qué comportamiento buscas?

Comment: toda  había  sigue el error no valida el auto complete pasa  por ensima  no reacciona  a la validación. @Gerry  gracias  ,no la ejecuta

Comment: @juangomez Veo que incluiste una pantalla en tu pregunta, pero está cortada: ¿podrías mostrarla completa?

Comment: hola @Gerry  ya esta actualizada  gracias.

Comment: @juangomez El error se debe a que el atributo `centro_costo_fullname` no trae valor; revisa la respuesta actualizada con la solución.